# Spring Web Application Authentication (advise)

Tags: spring, security, extjs, spring-security

I'm going to start the development of an web application system with multiple modules. The system will be built over Springframework, which is the reason why I'm going to use Spring Security. However, I have doubts about the choice of the authentication system.

The idea is to create restufull services that will be consumed by extjs pages (in case of web application) and mobile application.

Please suggest alternative authentication systems (more current). I have minimal expertise in system security and I'm worried about how to protect user credentials while maintaining a high level of response speed.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you have no prior experience with Spring Security, I would still recomend that you use it:

- It works very well out of the box with minumum configuration effort.
- There is alot of support available because it has become the de facto standard security implementation on many full stack solutions. It is unlikely that you will run into a problem that has not been solved before
- Spring Security is very robust and well tested.
- out-of-the box integration for almost anything i can think of
- finally, spring-security is ment for the springframework. The integration is flawless. Why give up the best part the framework has to offer?

Response speed should not be a criteria when selecting security framwork. Usually repsonse speed is slow due to bad software design or configuration issues. I have never ecountered a system that was slow due to the selected security framework.

I started using Spring Security a few years ago. It took me less than a week to set it up and It has worked properly ever since.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I use Spring Security since a few months ago but in a simple way and it's looks great so that's why I'm going to use it in this project. Can you recomend me any Open Source IAM System?

Comment: @user2378554 Not really, depends on your needs (public, private, military, singel sign on etc...). Usually IAM systems comes from the client and you will have to live with what they supply/use. On my own projects I Used AD and OpenLDAP. OpenLDAP is very good, and I do recomend it. I have some collegues that used OpenId as an authentivation base for SSO, and they said it works pretty well. However, I have no personal experiance with OpenID.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to go for simple authentication then this can easily be achieved mentioning it in Deployment Descriptors , you can specify Authorization Constraint, Security Constraints for Resources, Authentication mechanism and all . pls have a look at this link :

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkbaa.html